# vscode no tengo permiso suficiente y no deja guardar

Tags: vscode, windows10, powershell

muy buen día estaba programando en vscode para **Windows** (pongo bastante énfasis en Windows por que en internet la gran mayoría de soluciones son para Linux, Ubuntu o Mac pero no e visto casi soluciones para Windows) y me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

nunca me había pasado esto, en tutoriales para otro OS aparece algunos comandos que no tengo en
Windows la gran mayoría es con sudo ejemplo:

```
sudo chown -R username directory_name
```

pero tengo entendido que debe de haber una solución semejante para Windows os pero hasta ahora no he encontrado nada en internet alguien sabe que paso y como se puede solucionar?... gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Windows podrías probar modificando los permisos del directorio.
Seleccionas la carpeta -> Propiedades -> y miras que permisos tienes en atributos. Si solo tienes los de lectura desmarcalo para que puedas guardarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deja lo checo y te digo si funciono

Comment: es normal que el archivo en el que estaba trabajando ya no este y cuando creo otro con el mismo nombre no aparece?

Comment: No es normal...no se estará guardando el archivo en realidad. Has probado a guardar otro tipo de archivo en ese directorio? Asegúrate de que estas guardando el archivo donde es. Pudiste cambiar los permisos?

Comment: si pude cambiar los permisos, lo que me llamo la atención es que intentaba crear un archivo .php del mismo nombre que el anterior y se borraban

Comment: Y si pruebas a crear otro con otro nombre se te crea? o te sigue dando problemas? @ulisesalvarez

Comment: parece ser que fue un bug del windows ya que reinicie la computadora y ya me dejo crear el archivo con el mismo nombre de todos modos agradezco tus respuestas y por darle seguimiento a mi problema

Comment: Perfe, de nada!! @ulisesalvarez